# sounds keep on playing over each other

Tags: javascript, audio

I am using mySound to play a sound depending on whether a certain condition is met.  I am having a problem where the sounds play over each other even when the conditions are not met.  here is my code any ideas?

```
Game.countAnimals = function(playerGo) {
  var count = {bulls:0, cows:0};
  Game.counter = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < playerGo.length; i++) {
    var digPresent = playerGo.indexOf(Game.score[i]);
    if (playerGo[i] == Game.score[i]) {
      count.bulls++;
    }
    else if (digPresent>=0) {
      count.cows++;
    }
    Game.counter++
    if (count.bulls === playerGo.length && Game.counter < 7){
      mySound2 = new Audio("sounds/Freedom%20Tastes%20Good.mp3");
      mySound2.play(); 
    }
    else if (count.bulls !== playerGo.length && Game.counter < 7) {
      mySound1 = new Audio("sounds/Ass%20is%20dead.mp3");
      mySound1.play();
    }
    else if (Game.counter > 7 ){
      mySound = new Audio("sounds/Kill%20You%20Dog.mp3");
      mySound.play(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop all other sounds before playing a new one. Also, don't instantiate sounds in the function, when needed - you only have three sounds, so instantiate them when the page loads, outside the function.

So the fixed snippet should look something like this:

```
var mySound = new Audio("sounds/Kill%20You%20Dog.mp3");
var mySound1 = new Audio("sounds/Ass%20is%20dead.mp3");
var mySound2 = new Audio("sounds/Freedom%20Tastes%20Good.mp3");
Game.countAnimals = function(playerGo) {
  var count = {bulls:0, cows:0};
  Game.counter = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < playerGo.length; i++) {
    var digPresent = playerGo.indexOf(Game.score[i]);
    if (playerGo[i] == Game.score[i]) {
      count.bulls++;
    }
    else if (digPresent>=0) {
      count.cows++;
    }
    Game.counter++
    if (count.bulls === playerGo.length && Game.counter < 7){
      stopAllSounds();
      mySound2.play(); 
    }
    else if (count.bulls !== playerGo.length && Game.counter < 7) {
      stopAllSounds();
      mySound1.play();
    }
    else if (Game.counter > 7 ){
      stopAllSounds();
      mySound.play(); 
    }

function stopAllSounds() {
    mySound.pause();
    mySound1.pause();
    mySound2.pause();
    // rewind them
    mySound.currentTime = 0;
    mySound1.currentTime = 0;
    mySound2.currentTime = 0;
}
```